# In Java how can I redirect all future System.out.println outputs to a new terminal window I just opened?

Tags: java, system.out

In a little Java app, I am opening a new command line prompt for windows with `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");`

Is it possible after that to redirect all subsequent `System.out.println()` outputs to there?
I've looked around and I found `System.setOut();` but then, what do I set it to, to identify the new terminal window I just opened?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it *can't* be this easy, but: There's [`Process#getOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--), which gives you an `OutputStream` you can write to that writes to `stdin` on the process.

So in theory, `System.setOut(new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream()))`... (You may want one of the other `PrintStream` constructors.)

Comment: If I do ```Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe"); System.setOut(new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream()));```, System.out does not write anymore to the console the java app started from and does not write to the new one... If I open it by double clicking the jar, a new console is opened but nothing is sent there...